# Directed matrix to undirected matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, adjacency-matrix

I have directed network matrix which i want to convert to undirected matrix in MATLAB . Suppose i have following directed matrix

```
 G = [0 1 0 1; 0 0 1 1; 1 1 0 1; 0 0 0 0]
```

which i want to convert to following undirected matrix

```
Y = [0 1 1 1; 1 0 1 1; 1 1 0 1; 1 1 1 0]
```

I run the following code

```
 for i = 1 : m
    for j = 1 : n
        if G(i,j) == 1  
           G(j,i) = G(i,j);

        else 
            G(i,j)= 0 ;
        end

   end
  end
```

This code runs successfully but instead of overwriting matrix G I want a function which create a new undirected matrix Y from the directed matrix G

Comment: Why can't you simply start with `Y = G;` and replace `G` with `Y` in the subsequent code?

Answer (score 2):

Efficient way

```
 Y = G + G' > 0;
```

by Akira Agata

Comment: Even shorter: `Y=G|G';`. Output will be a logical, though.